# oauth2 for alexa skills and linking account

Tags: oauth-2.0, alexa-skills-kit

I trying to set up Oauth2 for linking account for an Alexa skill. My current back end runs in python/flask and I'm thinking of using rauth library to do so.

I have very little understanding of Oauth2 and I am looking for sample code that shows how to share resources with the an Alexa skill. Does anyone have a good example?

Answer (score 0):

Account linking works the same way for all languages and you should be familiar with `OAuth2` to configure account linking in developer portal.

Read this answer about [OAuth2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48584309/1574023)

In Alexa users can link account in two ways:

> 1. From the skill detail card in the Alexa app while enabling the skill.
> 2. From a link account card in the Alexa app after making a request that
>      requires authentication.

When you link an account with your skill, every subsequent request from the skill will include an access token. You can then use this `accessToken` to get associated data for linked account.

```
"session": {
        "new": true,
        "sessionId": "amzn1.echo-api.session.xxxxxxxxxxx",
        "application": {
            "applicationId": "amzn1.ask.skill.xxxxxxxxxx"
        },
        "user": {
            "userId": "amzn1.ask.account.xxxxxxx",
            "accessToken": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

Except for the code to send an **Account Link card** there is **no coding involved** in link-an-account process.